# Ubuntu Rails 4 Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip, ubuntu-14.04

I've seen similar post with this error but none of them fixed my problem. I'm using ImageMagick (6.9.0.8)and Paperclip for uploading images to my Rails 4 app. It is working on my development machine, a Mac, but not on my DigitalOcean account (Ubuntu 14.04, Nginx, Unicorn). When Paperclip tries saving different sizes of the images, ImageMagick give the error:

Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError

I'm using the Paperclip 4.2.1 and Cocaine .0.5.5 gems. In my Rails model I have:

```
has_attached_file :photo_image, :styles => { :medium => "330x250#", :small => "150x120#", :thumb => "120x100#" }, 
                            :url => "/system/dadverts/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
                            :path => ":rails_root/public/system/dadverts/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
                            :default_url => "300250ad.png"

validates_attachment_content_type :photo_image, :content_type => /\Aimage/
```

In my production environment settings I have:

```
Processing by AdvertisementsController#create as HTML
I, INFO -- :   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8hHWBxpydUyA1MEucXtnSvvRvHc38LcM1hbb8Is/cd4=", "advertisement"=>{"customer_name"=>"Kayak Venice", "ad_network_name"=>"Recon Outpost", "sitead_location_id"=>"1", "publish_date(1i)"=>"2015", "publish_date(2i)"=>"3", "publish_date(3i)"=>"14", "expiration_date(1i)"=>"2020", "expiration_date(2i)"=>"3", "expiration_date(3i)"=>"14", "keywords_alt_text"=>"", "sort_order"=>"1", "local_ad"=>"0", "zipcode"=>"00000", "photo_image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000005c93038 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150314-2186-1jc6u31>, @original_filename="KayakLogoConcept3.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"advertisement[photo_image]\"; filename=\"KayakLogoConcept3.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, "render_options"=>"1", "click_thru_url"=>"", "external_media_embed"=>""}, "advertisment"=>{"publish"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Create Advertisement"}
I,  INFO -- : Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH file -b --mime '/tmp/af961aaf697aaa71682a6e9716d6034520150314-2186-pxyhur.png'
I,  INFO -- : Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/af961aaf697aaa71682a6e9716d6034520150314-2186-o1r33b.png[0]' 2>/dev/null
I,  INFO -- : [paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
I,  INFO -- : Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/af961aaf697aaa71682a6e9716d6034520150314-2186-o1r33b.png[0]' 2>/dev/null
I,  INFO -- : [paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
I,  INFO -- : Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/af961aaf697aaa71682a6e9716d6034520150314-2186-o1r33b.png[0]' 2>/dev/null
I,  INFO -- : [paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
I,  INFO -- : Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH file -b --mime '/tmp/af961aaf697aaa71682a6e9716d6034520150314-2186-91e4eo.png'
I,  INFO -- : Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/af961aaf697aaa71682a6e9716d6034520150314-2186-fwjtt8.png[0]' 2>/dev/null
I,  INFO -- : [paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
I,  INFO -- : Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/af961aaf697aaa71682a6e9716d6034520150314-2186-fwjtt8.png[0]' 2>/dev/null
I,  INFO -- : [paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
I,  INFO -- : Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/af961aaf697aaa71682a6e9716d6034520150314-2186-fwjtt8.png[0]' 2>/dev/null
I,  INFO -- : [paperclip] An error was received while processing: #<Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError>
I,  INFO -- : Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH file -b --mime '/tmp/af961aaf697aaa71682a6e9716d6034520150314-2186-k19vf3.png'
I,  INFO -- :   Rendered advertisements/_form.html.erb (65.2ms)
```

Comment: Requires full backtrace of error to investigate problem.

Comment: maxd, I've attached a sample from my production log.

Comment: maxd, it's a plain PNG file, created in Illustrator. I don't remember installing any special processors. I'm thinking I may have to re-install IM but I hoping someone here answers this. Thxs.

Answer (score 1):

This error class has [description](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/dca87ec5d8038b2d436a75ad6119c8eb67b73e70/lib/paperclip/errors.rb#L23):

```
# Will be thrown when ImageMagic cannot determine the uploaded file's
# metadata, usually this would mean the file is not an image.
```

This is mean that you are trying to process not image file. Seems like it can be related to incorrect extension of temporary file. Look at this file extension:

```
af961aaf697aaa71682a6e9716d6034520150314-2186-o1r33b.png[0]
```

As you can see it has [0] at the end. So, try to investigate why this extension is appear. Seems like you are using custom processor base on Cocaine. I think problem can be related to it.

Answer (score 0):

Anything new for this issue?
I got the same problem and open a new issue on github:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/cocaine/issues/84

Comment: I changed the load path for Paperclip in my environments > production.rb file to  Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/" and added LD_LIBRARY_PATH = "/usr/bin/"